# Is there a format spec that will output a OS-specific newline?

Tags: format, rust

In `format!(..)`, `print!(..)`, `println!(..)` etc. it's easy enough to insert values in various formats, however the docs show no way of adding an OS specific newline (e.g. `'\n'` in unices/MacOS X, `"\r\n"` on Windows). Is there such a format specifier? If not, how should one put newlines in their formatted strings/outputs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe so.

That said, with the exception of Notepad, just about everything on Windows has long since learned that `\n` is as much a newline as `\r\n`.  In fact, the only other time I have line ending issues is badly ported UNIX software that refuses to believe in the existence of `\r\n` newlines.

In other words, unless you have a specific reason for doing so, just stick to `\n`.

If you *do* have a specific reason, it's probably simplest to define a `NL` constant somewhere (I couldn't find one in the stdlib):

```rust
#[cfg(windows)] pub const NL: &'static str = "\r\n";
#[cfg(not(windows))] pub const NL: &'static str = "\n";
```

Comment: As a follow-up, Notepad gained the ability to handle `\n` line endings in 2018.